# Morphing animated mesh into a shape

Tags: animation, mesh

I have an animated object in the shape of a spikey ball which is used as a collission.

The vertex structure of the mesh is complex and the spikes, along with surface irregularities, interact oddly when colliding with other surfaces.

I'm trying to convert the spikey ball into a simple sphere which improves these collisions, but when I go Edit Mode > Add Sphere, the Sphere does not move with the original mesh when the animation is placed.

I'd have thought going into Edit Mode and adding a new shape would have it become 'part' of the overall mesh, but it seems there's something else which dicates "which parts follow the animation".

What's a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you simply give a Rigid Body > Collisions > Shape > Sphere to your object?

Comment: Apart from agreeing with @moonboots that changing the collision shape would be the easiest solution, I am wondering how do you make the spikey ball move? If a mesh added in _Edit Mode_ doesn't follow along it sounds as if the origin of the object isn't moving - and that makes me wonder if the spikey ball is moving with shape keys or posing by armature or with geometry nodes simulation? Because if something like this is going here, the simple solution might not work either or at least not without any changes.